# First instruction in NASM source missing from machine code (disassembly)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm calling a function from C that I define using NASM 2.13.3.1. I'm developing in Visual C++ Professional 2017 15.9.21.

Here is the C code:

```
#include <string.h>

extern _begin_asm_func(int, const char*, void*);

struct MyStruct
{
    int64_t a;
    int64_t b;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    struct MyStruct x;
    x.a = 1;
    x.b = 2;

    char str[] = "Hi";
    int len = strlen(str);
    
    _begin_asm_func(len, str, (void *)&x);

    return 0;
}
```

NASM Code:

```
global _begin_asm_func

SECTION .data

SECTION .text
_begin_asm_func:
        ; align stack pointer to 16-byte boundary because return address (8 bytes) pushed by call \
        PUSH rbx ;
        PUSH r12 ;
        PUSH r13 ;
        PUSH r14 ;
        PUSH r15 ;
        ; five pushes to save non-volitile registers for use later should also align stack

        MOV r12, rcx ; store length in r12
        MOV r13, rdx ; store string pointer in r13
        MOV r14, r8  ; store pointer to data structure in r14
        MOV r15, [r8] ; store first field value
        
        ; useful stuff will go here later...

        POP r15 ;
        POP r14 ;
        POP r13 ;
        POP r12 ;
        POP rbx ;
        RET ; access violation happens here
```

And here is the debugger output:

```
global _begin_asm_func

SECTION .data

SECTION .text

_begin_synergy_asm:
00007FF7E37718A0  push        r12
00007FF7E37718A2  push        r13
00007FF7E37718A4  push        r14
00007FF7E37718A6  push        r15
00007FF7E37718A8  mov         r12, rcx
00007FF7E37718AB  mov         r13, rdx
00007FF7E37718AE  mov         r14, r8
00007FF7E37718B1  mov         r15, qword ptr[r8]
00007FF7E37718B4  pop         r15
00007FF7E37718B6  pop         r14
00007FF7E37718B8  pop         r13
00007FF7E37718BA  pop         r12
00007FF7E37718BC  pop         rbx
00007FF7E37718BD  ret
```

The seg fault / access violation happens on return.  Two things immediately jumped out at me.  First, the first `push` to `rbx` is missing, and second, the address of the second push is on a 4-byte boundary.  So it seems to me that the instructions are being mis-aligned by nasm, so the call is landing on the second instruction instead of the first.  That mis-aligns the stack so that the number of pops don't match the mumber of pushes, so that `ret` gets the wrong value for the return address.

Assuming alignment is the actual problem, how do I tell nasm to align the label for the function?  I know the align directive is only for aligning data.

If that isn't the issue, then what is it and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Minor nitpick: `align` is also used for aligning code in NASM, which is why it defaults to emit 90h (`nop` opcode) bytes to do the aligning. That means you can put `align` before a code label (like for data) or even after the label. However, this is unlikely to help here.

Comment: This usually  happens if the preceding comment line is accidentally continued to the `push rbx`.

Comment: @ecm I tried align just in case and it did not make a difference, as you predicted.

Comment: @Jester Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: An example would be an accidental backslash at the end of the preceding line. Try putting a blank line before the `push rbx`.

Comment: And so there is an accidental backslash!  Thank you for pointing me in that direction.  I feel foolish for not seeing that, but it explains everything nicely.

Comment: Relevant: https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392663

Comment: Not a [mcve], code in the question doesn't contain a \ and copy-pasting into a .asm doesn't repro the problem.  But yes, you did correctly diagnose the problem from looking at disassembly.  No need to bring MSVC into it.

Comment: Added the backslash in my original code. Note sure why it didn't copy over.